# Imposm installed, but missing modules

Tags: python, imposm

I installed `imposm` according to instructions [in the manual](http://imposm.org/docs/imposm/2.5.0/install.html), but some module seems to be missing. What's wrong with it?

```
  File "mapping.py", line 2, in <module>
    from imposm.mapping import (
ImportError: cannot import name FixInvalidPolygons
```

Trying to run the line:

```
> from imposm.mapping import Options
ImportError: No module named mapping
```

Answer (score 1):

as per source code of [imposm.mapping](https://github.com/omniscale/imposm/blob/master/imposm/mapping.py), it has `FixInvalidPolygons` class. Please check `PUTHONPATH`, it must have directory where `imposm` installed.

Comment: found out that i had only imposm.parser installed

Answer (score 1):

Found out the reason. I had installed `imposm.parser`, and then `pip install imposm` did nothing, it stated that all requirements were already met. So I did

```
sudo pip uninstall imposm
sudo apt-get install libtokyocabinet-dev
sudo pip install imposm
```